# How can I have a Configurable attribute populated from a source

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, source-model

I have a product attribute, which is populated by a source model which is extended from AbstractSource. Because of this the attribute is not set with 'is_user_defined' = 1 and therefore I am not able to use this attribute as a configurable option.

So my question is... How can I create an attribute that can be used as a configurable option whilst being populated from the database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General info:
Here are the rules for using an attribute in a configurable product.
They come from `\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::canUseAttribute`

```
public function canUseAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attribute)
{
    return $attribute->getIsGlobal() == \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL &&
        $attribute->getIsVisible() &&
        $attribute->usesSource() &&
        $attribute->getIsUserDefined();
}
```

So basically, the attribute should be global  (is_global = 1 in talbe `catalog_eav_attribute`), is visible (is_visible = 1 in table `catalog_eav_attribute`), usesSource (type is select or multiselect  and source_model is not empty - all in table `eav_attribute`) and is user defined (is_user_defined = 1 in the eav_attribute table)

Now for your specific problem.  You can change `is_user_defined` to 1 in the eav_attribute table for your specific product.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have done the job, I did set 'is_user_defined' when creating the attribute with code, but this didn't seem to work so I am not sure why it works when I have set it to true in the eav table.